# Gulp src does not find pattern

Tags: gulp, glob

I'm tryng to create a new gulp task to run into my application and look for all '.fragment.sass' files.

I wrote:

```
gulp.task('sassFragments', () => {
  return gulp
    .src('./src/**/*.fragment.sass')
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(sassGlob())
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' })).on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(concat('fragments_style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
})
```

but no fragments_style.css is created in /build/assets/css folder.

I have another task which does similar using src('./src/**/*.sass') to generate a **style.css** file and works great!

**I think there is a issue with .src method, that is not matching this '.fragment.sass' pattern.**

Can anyone help me?

- *Gulp version: 3.9.1*

Comment: You probably want `'./src/**/*.fragment.sass'`  note the slash after `src`.

Comment: written mistake. I've edited.

Comment: Does your `debug` pipe write out the `*.fragment.sass` file?  And assuming you are using `gulp-sass-glob` all its examples are using `.scss` extensions - does it support `.sass` files?

Comment: Yes, I have another task to generate a compilated style.css searching for *.sass files using debug pipe and works well. 

And gulp-sass-glob suport .sass.

Comment: It seems to be an error with pipe sass(), when I remove it, my fragment_style.css is generated but not compiled as css file, it remains with the .sass sintaxe.

Comment: I hate to suggest it but I would remove the `sassGlob` pipe and those type of imports and see if you can get it to work.  Or just use a different source file that doesn't have sassGlob imports.